# What was the role of quality in early manufacturing facilities?

Tags: industry

We all know that quality is a very important thing in todays industry. But was it always like that? What was the role of production quality before we had Shewhart, Deming and so on? Did companies and government-driven manufacturing facilities always worry about quality and if so, how did they try to achieve it?

Comment: I think I'd disagree with your first statement. "You get what you pay for" is as true today as it ever was. Certainly, repeated legislation has improved quality where it directly affects product safety but equally consumer spending will drive manufacturers to the cheapest materials and components that they can get away with.

Comment: This is such an interesting question. A Phd thesis waiting to be written. You'd end up tracking the history of the idea of 'quality'. Can't answer, but wish I could.